# Android Studio - Cannot resolve symbol 'BuildConfig'

Tags: java, android, buildconfig

I am trying to import

```
import com.example.app.BuildConfig;
```

but When I am doing so, this error is coming

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'BuildConfig'
```

and then I am doing this:-

```
TextView version = findViewById(R.id.version);
        version.setText(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
```

and I am rececving this error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'BuildConfig'
```

there is a suggestion for the second error that I should import the class. But what should I import?
[these are the suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtiND.png)

Comment: What is your `package` value in the `<manifest>` element of your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: One has to build first, in order to have it generated ...just use auto-complete for the `import`.